# Alternative Text for images missing while merging using iText7

Tags: pdf, accessibility, itext7

We are using iText7 to merge different PDF documents which are already 508 compliant. While merging the documents alternative text for some of the images is lost and it is random for different cases. The individual PDF's that I use have the alternate text for all the images before merging. How can I resolve this and still retain the alternative text for images?

I have already tried using AddAltTags example, but this provides a facility to add tags in the program but I would like to retain the already existing alternative text.

I am using the below code to merge:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i7ns-samples/develop/itext/itext.publications/itext.publications.jumpstart/tutorial/chapter07/C07E04_MergePDFADocuments.cs

Comment: did you already contact https://itextpdf.com/en/support ?

Comment: Could you share the documents, so that we can reproduce the problem?